Struggling to prove 14.26 (b) in Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds"
I'm struggling to prove proposition 14.26 (b) in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds $\def\w{\omega} \def\W{\Omega} \def\h{\eta} \def\bv{\textbf{v}} \def\sgn{\text{sgn}} \def\a{\alpha} \def\b{\beta} \def\s{\sigma} \def\alt{\text{Alt}} \def\SS{\mathbb{S}} \def\RR{\mathbb{R}} \def\td{\text{d}} \def\dx{\text{d}x}$.
Proposition 14.26 Let $F:M\to N$ be smooth. Then
(a) $F^*:\W^k(N)\to \W^k(M)$ is linear over $\RR$.
(b) $F^*(\w\wedge \h) = (F^*\w) \wedge (F^*\h)$.
(c) In any smooth chart
$$F^*\left(\sum_I \w_I\dx_{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge\dx^{i_k}\right) = \sum_I (\w_I\circ F) \td(x_{i_1}\circ F)\wedge\cdots\wedge \td(x_{i_k} \circ F).$$

My attempt: suppose $\w\in\W^k(N)$ and $\h\in\W^l(N)$. Unpacking definitions we get
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& F^*(\w\wedge\h)_p(\bv_1,\ldots,\bv_{k+l}) \\
 & = (\w\wedge\h)_{F(p)}\left(dF_p(\bv_1),\ldots,dF_p(\bv_{k+l})\right) \\
 & = \frac{(k+l)!}{k!l!}\alt(\w\otimes\h)_{F(p)}\left(dF_p(\bv_1),\ldots,dF_p(\bv_{k+l})\right) \\
 & = \frac{1}{k!l!} \sum_{\s\in\SS_{k+l}}\sgn(\s)(\w\otimes\h)_{F(p)}\left(dF_p(\bv_{\s(1)}),\ldots,dF_p(\bv_{\s(k+l)})\right) \\
 & = \frac{1}{k!l!} \sum_{\s\in\SS_{k+l}}\sgn(\s)\w\left(dF_p(\bv_{\s(1)}),\ldots,dF_p(\bv_{\s(k)})\right) \h\left(dF_p(\bv_{\s(k+1)}),\ldots,dF_p(\bv_{\s(k+l)})\right) 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
yet it's not clear how to 'separate' the last expression into sums over $\SS_k$ and $\SS_l$. For example the expression
$$\left(\sum_{\a\in\SS_k} (\bv_{\a(1)},\ldots,\bv_{\a(k)})\right)
\left(\sum_{\b\in\SS_l} (\bv_{\b(1)},\ldots,\bv_{\b(k)})\right)$$
contains as one of its summands
$$\a(\bv_{1},\bv_{2},\ldots,\bv_{k})\b(\bv_{1},\bv_{2},\ldots,\bv_{l}),$$
yet such a summand is not contained in
$$\left(\sum_{\s\in\SS_{k+l}} (\bv_{\s(1)},\ldots,\bv_{\s(k+l)})\right).$$

Is your definition of $\mathrm{Alt}$ correct? Somehow I am thinking you should have only those $\sigma$ such that they permute $1, \ldots, k$ and $k+1, \ldots, k+l$. In this case, such subset of $\mathrm{S}_{k+l}$ is in an obvious bijection with $\mathrm{S}_k \times \mathrm{S}_l$.

@WilliamM. Unless I'm missing something, we seem to have the definitions $\omega\wedge\eta = (k+l)!/(k!l!)\text{Alt}(\omega\otimes\eta)$ and $\text{Alt}(\tau) =  \sum_{\sigma\in \mathbb{S}m} \text{sgn}(\tau) \omega (v{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(n)})$. These two together seem to give $\omega\wedge\eta =  \frac{1}{k!l!} \sum_{\sigma\in \mathbb{S}{k+l}} \text{sgn}(\sigma) (\omega\otimes\eta) (v{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k+l)}) = \frac{1}{k!l!} \sum_{\sigma\in \mathbb{S}{k+l}} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \omega(v{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k)})\eta(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k+l)}).$

Shuffles. You need to understand how $S_k$ and $S_l$ lie inside of $S_{k+l}$ in order to simplify your expression. Look up shuffles.

I think then you need to prove that if $\sigma(i) = j$ para $1 \leq i \leq k$ and $k+1 \leq j \leq k+l$ then the summand corresponding to $\sigma$ will either be zero or get cancelled by the summand corresponding to $\sigma^{-1}$. So then you will have a sum only over the desired $\sigma$ (everything else that mixes the indices gets killed).

All you need to write is basically the first two lines you wrote down. The wedge product of 2 forms is basically the outer product of the 2 forms followed by complete skew-symmetrization.

Why do you need to separate into sums over $S_k$ and $S_l$? Continuing from your last line, which I shall call $(@)$, we get
\begin{align}
(@)&=\frac{1}{k!l!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+l}}\text{sgn}(\sigma)(F^*\omega)_p(v_{\sigma(1)},\dots, v_{\sigma(k)})\cdot (F^*\eta)_p(v_{\sigma_{(k+1)}},\dots, v_{\sigma(k+l)})\\
&=\frac{1}{k!l!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+l}}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\cdot ((F^*\omega)\otimes (F^*\eta))_p(v_{\sigma(1)},\dots, v_{\sigma(k+1)})\\
&=((F^*\omega)\wedge (F^*\eta))_p(v_{1},\dots, v_{k+1}).
\end{align}
Since $p\in M$ and $v_1,\dots, v_{k+l}\in T_pM$ are arbitrary, this shows $F^*(\omega\wedge\eta)=(F^*\omega)\wedge(F^*\eta)$.
